# Kill the parent of a child pipe process

Tags: bash, process, pipe, kill

I have a small script to demonstrate what I want to do

```
#!/bin/bash
> z
tail -f z | grep 'd' &
echo $!
```

The `$!` gives the PID of the grep process. I want to be able to kill the tail process at the same time as killing the grep process. Doing `kill "pid of grep"`does not kill the tail process. Nor does `killall grep`. I could use `killall tail` but I think this would be dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enclose your command with parentheses:

```
( tail -f z | grep 'd' ) &
kill -- -$!
```

This will kill the whole sub-process.

Here, by specifying a negative PID to kill, we kill the whole process group. See `man 1 kill`:

> Negative PID values may be used to choose whole process 
>   groups; see the PGID column in ps command output.

Or `man 2 kill`:

> If pid is less than -1, then sig is sent to every 
>   process in the process group whose ID is -pid.

However, `kill -PID` will only work [if job control is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20888200/7233423) in `bash` (the default for interactive shells). Else, your subprocess won't have a dedicated process group and the kill command will fail with `kill: (-PID) - No such process`

To work around that, either activate job control in `bash` (`set -m`), or use `pkill -P $!`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I executed this script and echoed the $!. Then I killed the process and appended "r", then "d". But the grep was still running and it echoed the "d" to stdout. Furthermore, killing that pid still shows the tail and grep in `ps ux`

Comment: @user1005909 Sorry, I answered too quickly. Answer updated

Comment: Looks like there's an extra - on -$!. Anyway, this works only if the kill statement is in the bash script. Echoing the pid, then using `kill -- pid` from another shell doesn't work.

Comment: @user1005909 The minus sign is intended, don't remove it! I have amended my answer with some documentation.

Comment: I see. I was getting `-bash: kill: (-pid) - No such process`. But this lead me to use `pkill -P pid` which works as I want.

Comment: @user1005909 That's weird. I have never had any issue with the command `kill -- -PID`. I've just tried it again with Debian, Ubuntu and SLES, and it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51665/discussion-between-user1005909-and-xhienne).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it didn't work for me

```
( tail -f z | grep 'd' ) &
kill -- -$!
```

I just used a named pipe instead of an unnamed pipe

```
rm -f tailfifo; mkfifo tailfifo
tail -n 0 -f mylog.log >tailfifo &
TAIL_PID=$!
grep --line-buffered someword <tailfifo >outputfile &
GREP_PID=$!
# .. ..
kill $TAIL_PID
kill $GREP_PID
```

Comment: You tried what?  The other answer?  If you refer to another answer, please say so clearly.

Answer (score 0):

[xhienne's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336897/262636)
does not work in non-interactive sh (dash) .
use `()` will not create a process group,
so `sh -c '(sleep 6m | sleep 8m) & kill -- -$!'` will not work.

However, you can still use `ps --no-headers --format pgid:1 $!`
to find the pgid of the whole pipe and kill it.

```bsh
sleep 6m | sleep 8m &
pgid=`ps -ho $!`
kill -- -$pgid
```

Moreover, using `()` in pipe will cause shell not create process group.

```bsh
pgid() {
    ps --no-headers --format pgid:1 $1
}

while true
do nc $ip $port
done | str2str -out tcpsvr://:5566 &
echo `pgid $!` == $$
wait
```